# Where are airdrop files located on ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, airdrop

I sent my files(pdf, docs...) from macbook to iphone but i did not open my files when received. And now i can not find my files anywhere. Is there anywhere or removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a file gets sent, you'll be given a popup menu with a list of apps in which to store the file. You have to pick one if you want to keep the file. If you just press Cancel, the file gets deleted. If the file(s) are photos or videos (compatible with ios) they end up in the photo album. If, however they are not compatible with any photo viewer installed, they seem to disappear without warning.

Comment: What if the pop doesn't show a list of apps?

Comment: I don't see any popup, I only hear a sound.

Comment: @SalalAslam i know it's been a while but in case someone else struggles with this issue. In my case the solution was to reboot the phone. Then the popup appears.